# Which is better, #fff or #FFF?

Tags: css

Which is better to define color?

```
color:#fff;
```

or

```
color:#FFF;
```

?

I like #FFF because it catch your eyes' focus faster than #fff. But PS returns lowercase, so I was wondering if lowercase hexadecimal is better than uppercase. Why this thread closed? o.Oa

Comment: You do realise they mean exactly the same thing, right?

Comment: I prefer caps as it's easier to spot when skimming.

Comment: #FFF has three less bits on than #fff... saves electricity.

Comment: *Better* in terms of what?

Comment: i prefer `#fff` as you don't have to press the shift key for the last three chars

Comment: @stephenmurdoch: micro-optimization ftl

Comment: This is quite silly. The specification states that it's case-insensitive in this regard.

Comment: think of the power saving over an entire websites lifetime by not pressing shift (on a twelve volt USB keyboard) each time you are entering a colour value.

Comment: @Mauro: Ah, but surely holding down the shift key for all three keys cost the same in terms of electricity as pushing it down once for the #? In that case, you'd be better off keeping it held down, because you get more bang for your buck, so to speak.

Comment: Depends, in the uk we dont need to press shift for a #, and the longer duration of the shift key press would consume more juice anyway :P its a moot point though.

Comment: @all: Hahahaha.. just curious. I like Tony's answer :P

Comment: @Mauro: If you don't need to hold down for the #, then yes, `#fff` is the most economical choice. But I would expect that tripping the switch is the significant part of the power consumption; so `#FFF` would consume more juice than `#fff`, but less per character; which really comes into play if you follow it up with a `;`, and need to shift for that as well, meaning that on balance, `#fff;` costs *more* than `#FFF;`.

Comment: @Felix Kling I was wondering if there is relation between my question and coding convention in CSS. Read all the comments, I don't think so, hehhe. But my opinion, #FFF is more readable than #fff.

Comment: It's amazing and amusing to see people debating over the implications of pressing the Shift key.

Comment: @Unicorn: What's life without a good debate every now and then? Trying to debate religion or politics never works out, so one has to reach for something not divisive or even significant in the slightest. :)

Comment: @BoltClock I use the CAPSLOCK button when typing FFF then hold shift to do the hash prefix, im evil.

Comment: Obviously `#fFf` is better. But how to choose with `#FfF`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Neither;

```
color: white;
```

In all seriousness, tho', it doesn't matter so long as it matches the general design of your site. (For example, SO or FB should use `#FFF`, while, say, Apple would use `#fff`. Matches the rounded corners better, you see?)

Comment: What about `#fc28d9` vs `#FC28D9`?

Comment: Don't be such a fancy-pants; just use `fuchsia`. P:

Comment: http://www.colourlovers.com/color/fc28d9

Comment: @Williham Totland thanks Wil :) I though point 5 here (http://sixrevisions.com/css/12-common-css-mistakes-web-developers-make/) is absolutely right.


@troelskn thanks, nice website.

Comment: Actually, point 5 is only kind of right. A lot of the time you'll want to violate the hell out of that rule; especially if you want your site to actually care about your user; using the system colors for selected text and such, for example, can only be done using color names (there's a slew of special color names for this purpose).

Comment: And the point 5 there is confused anyway; you haven't actually achieved anything by using #F00 (== #FF0000) instead of red; red, by its very definition, **is** #FF0000. The only thing you have achieved is that the browser now display what it thinks *#FF0000* is; which still may or may not be the color you are after (what with color calibration and whatnot). Color names have defined hex value equivalents, and using the hex value equivalents instead of color names only serve to confuse matters and make your CSS more difficult to read. (A couple of other points in there are a bit off, as well…)

Comment: @WillihamTotland that color is actually Razzle Dazzle Rose according to Name That Color.

Answer (score 48):

It depends what colour you want. #fff is 'white' and #FFF is 'WHITE'. Your choice.

Comment: alright, thank you. @acme ahahah it's funny :)

Answer (score 9):

The convention for Hex in CS has always been uppercase (as far as I know), with web designers it tends to be lowercase - the only thing that is "better" is sticking to one scheme and using it only.  Switching back and forth just looks messy.

Comment: With PS CS5, the color picker returns lowercase hex code. Yes I agree, I type color name just for testing, but sometimes I forgot to change it to hex code. Thanks, Mauro.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about case sensitivity then it does not effect.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_color_names

> In HTML, documents using 4.01
>   specifications colors can be specified
>   by name. Names are defined in this
>   context to be case-insensitive. Using
>   colors in HTML has been deprecated in
>   favor of CSS.favor of CSS.

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sFgtm/)

Comment: No he isn’t. `#FFF` is completely valid: `#RGB` is an abbreviation for `#RRGGBB` in CSS.

Comment: @Konrad: Ok. If #fff is valid then I removed the part that is making it invalid.

Comment: And #fff is observiation of ? Or it is valid color code.

Comment: yes, you can define white with #fff. Thanks for your answer anyway.
@Konrad Rudolph thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Pff I prefer

```
color: rgb(255,255,255)
```

Comment: Meh, `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);`

Comment: I often use color picker from PS or PHOTO-PAINT and it returns hexa color value, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Between below two there is no difference.

```
color:#fff;
or

color:#FFF;
```

[CSS Color Codes](http://www.quackit.com/css/css_color_codes.cfm)

Go for : #FFFFFF this kind of hexa color than rather than short hand.

In CSS, you define a color using either the hexadecimal color code, the RGB color code, or the actual color name. A benefit of using hexadecimal and RGB color codes is that you have many more options than just supplying a color name.

The color picker and chart on this page provide you with the hexadecimal color codes. The color picker also provides the RGB color code.

Hexadecimal color codes are often referred to as "hexadecimal colors", "hex colors codes", "color values" and a few other terms. "Hexadecimal color values" is probably the most accurate term as they are made up of hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: But `#fff` saves you three bytes, so what's the benefit of using `#ffffff` if they mean the same thing?

Comment: @Matt Huggins yeah, reducing file size never been a bad thing.

Comment: It is much easier to stick to 6 characters as regex and find and replace then does not need to account for 3 or 6 variations