# What is the best way to specify color in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In CSS, i have seen different developers using various methods to specify colors, say for example i have a DIV like

```
  <div class="container"> </div>
```

CSS

```
  .container
  {
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
  }
```

or

```
  .container
  {
   background-color:#ffffff;
  }
```

or

```
  .container
  {
   background-color:#FFF;
  }
```

or

```
  .container
  {
   background-color:#fff;
  }
```

or

```
  .container
  {
   background-color:white;
  }
```

I would like to know what is the best way to use colors in CSS. Thanks in advance

Comment: Updated. so what is the better way to follow?

Comment: I prefer #fff whenever it's possible. After that #ffffff and then rgb(a)-values. But I guess there is not "best way" to set a color.

Comment: Partial duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733172/which-is-better-fff-or-fff.

Comment: I gave it some extra thought: a case can be made for lowercase readability: `#b88b8b` vs `#B88B8B` (which is the only relevant example actually). From there-on it's just a matter of consistency.. My dino-gut screams that lowercase is 'just wrong style', but my dino-eyes disagree. Together with my brain (that knows that digits are usually the height of uppercase characters) they are currently converting my gut.

Comment: @GitaarLAB That's a good one; you should post that as an answer. If I had thought of that, I might have reconsidered closing as opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use full Hex code e.g : #3c3c3c , #212121 etc It is a good Practice to use proper hex codes.
Also Names of color can be used if you know the color better and don't need the hex code for it. Easy work.

Use :

```
.container{
     background-color: #ffffff ; /* or */
     background-color: white;
}
```

RGB abd RGBA can also be used but most of the designer prefer HEX short and easy to remind. 
I use RGBA for Transparent color.

Comment: Can you explain to the OP why lowercase hex is better than uppercase, and why six digits are better than three, because that's what they're asking about. Also, you should notice that not all color names are recognised by all browsers.

Comment: @MrLister Thats True . 
Six digit Hex codes are always best practice because few browser cannot ready three digit hex code, May cause issue in color. I have read this in some color theory article. 
Other thing small letter or caps Hex codes both are same, just to keep neat and tidy few designers use caps hex.

Comment: Please give an example of a browser (or browsers) that doesn't "read three digit hex code"

Answer (score 2):

As the others said before me, there's no method that's in any way "official" or "best.

I myself use the following:

```
.container
{
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

The reason for this is to have the clearest possible way (for me anyways) to modify colors with **Red Green Blue** (RGB) pattern.

On the top of the cake there is the **Alpha** -setup where from you can change the opacity of your elements without the global `opacity: 0.8;` setting which affects everything inside the div / other element.

If the alpha layer is not needed, you can always shorten it to `rgb(255,255,255);`.

Answer (score 0):

When available, use the three-character shorthand hexadecimal color value, and always use lowercase characters within any hexadecimal color value.

```
.container
{
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Just a not, using a single `space` before value is also a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Using hex value of a color is always a better value. Because it defines uniformity across the browsers and devices, whereas defining color name may lead to some differences.

```
.container{
     background-color:#ffffff;
 }
```

Also it is better to define hex values in lowercase letters, again due to implementations across rendering platform.

```
.container{
     background-color:#ffffff;
 }
```

For chosing between the short format and the long format, it hardly matters because they both refers to the same value.

Comment: Please give some examples regarding "implementations across rendering platform"? What platform 'requires' lowercase? The spec states that both full and 'websafe'-set are case-insensitive.