# Is there a performance difference between the different css color formats

Tags: html, css

There are many formats to define a color in css:

- Hexadecimal colors: `#FFF` or `#fff`
- RGB colors: `rgb(255, 255, 255)`
- RGBA colors: `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)`
- HSL colors: `hsl(0, 100%, 100%)`
- HSLA colors: `hsl(0, 100%, 100%, 1)`
- Predefined/Cross-browser color names: `white`

But are there differences in performance between these different formats? For example, does the browser take longer to understand that it has to render white pixels for color `rgb(255, 255, 255)` than for color `#FFF`?

I know that there are already similar questions on SO such as these:

- [Are there any cons to using color names in place of color codes in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230851/are-there-any-cons-to-using-color-names-in-place-of-color-codes-in-css)
- [#FFFFFF or “white” in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825015/ffffff-or-white-in-css)
- [Which is better, #fff or #FFF? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733172/which-is-better-fff-or-fff)

But none of them really provide an answer when it comes to performance on the browser side.

So could someone enlighten me on how browsers handle these different formats?

Comment: run some benchmark and see what you get but I doubt you will get any significant difference. Convervting between all the types should be a trivial/fast task for any browser

Comment: @TemaniAfif I alsothink that the difference is minimal, but out of simple curiosity I wanted to know if `#FFF` is more efficient thant `white`. I have no idea how I could conduct such a test.

Comment: `#fff` is faster than`white` I remember a benchmark on that, but the difference was extremely small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in the article I linked below using HEX code is better but not by much we are talking if you have 100,000 colors in your code then it will create 1ms difference between them.

but you can visit this link to get a more meaning full understanding of why is doesn't make that much of a difference

and to see if it really makes a difference run an audit on your website and see the performance difference for each and see which one is better if any.
[Link to answer](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-to-use-HEX-or-RGB-color-property-in-CSS-to-make-less-server-source-consumption-and-make-the-CSS-load-faster)

Comment: Thanks for the information and the link ;) Maybe you can extract more infos from this link to write it directly in the post for the future users